# Rails/MongoDB: How to query mongodb model with string to date typecast?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, casting, mongoid

I have a rails mongoid model with a string field end_date as follows

```rb
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :end_date, type: String
end
```

`end_date` is having values stored as `September 2021`, `January 2025` etc.
Now How can I find all the projects which has end_date less than current month?

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding correctly you want to compare date . You can use the following documentation to fit your purpose -

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/Date.html

Get the date in a controller method and then convert before comparing with the current date . Hopefully this answers the question .